# .NET runtime parser formats a date from xml before serialization considering Time Zone

Tags: .net, parsing, windows-phone, timezone, xml-serialization

I am generating classes for an XSD scheme with some tool. One of my auto-generated partial classes has a DateTime property called "dateTime":

```
private System.DateTime dateTimeField;

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public System.DateTime dateTime
{
    get
    {
        return this.dateTimeField;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((dateTimeField.Equals(value) != true))
        {
            this.dateTimeField = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("dateTime");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the attribute and its value the way i see it in the response:

```
<Arrival dateTime="2015-02-15T08:21:00+01:00" track="10">
```

However in my "dateTime" property the Time Zone is calculated automatically, considering the device set Time Zone and the value I' m able to work with is this:

"2015-02-15T09:21:00+02:00" ?!?!?!?!?!

If I manually change the "dateTime" prop to string instead of System.DateTime, again, I will see "2015-02-15T09:21:00+02:00" this inserted inside, and not "2015-02-15T08:21:00+01:00". How come this .NET automatic parser decides to calculate this date for me and how to fix this problem?